# Why does this mesh look different in object and edit modes?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, object-mode

I have a mesh without any modifiers and applied scale:

[image]

But when I'm trying to use edit mode, it looks different:

[image]

Where could the problem be?

Here's the blend file:
[image]

Comment: Hello, it looks like you have 2 meshes or objects overlapping, could you please share your file?

Comment: It seems that you have two objects very close to one another. The one with nails is very slightly "under" the one edited. Changing mode is recomputing the display. So perhaps, the numerical truncation is changing which mesh is rendered "above".

Comment: @moonboots yes, it is. I'm trying to create stockings, so I need to see all the meshes.

Comment: Couldyou please share your file?

Comment: @StefLAncien I've tried to hide mesh which is above, but main mesh still changing it's geometry.

Comment: "Main" mesh is foot or stocking ? It is very difficult to figure out what is happening "under the hood" because collection "Mercy" in collapsed. You could have there many things that could interfere...

Comment: @StefLAncien main mesh is stocking, and it is above foot.

Comment: Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ? Please remove everything that is not visible in the provided views, still preserving the problem.

Comment: @StefLAncien yes, I've added it to question.

Comment: @moonboots I've finally added blend file to question. You can check it out if you want to.

Comment: Try and disable *Shape Keys* in the *Object Data Properties* ?

Comment: @StefLAncien yes, that's the right answer, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created 2 shapekeys, bring their values back to 0 and select the *Basic* shapekey if you want to edit the original mesh:

[image]